# Split csv into small csv using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a `csv` (around 750MB of size). I have to split it into small `csv` each of size not more than 30Mb.

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
1,a,1,4
2,a,1,4
3,b,1,4
4,b,1,4
5,b,1,4
6,c,1,4
```

The constraint is that you cannot have same `c2` in different files.
(e.g one cannot have half `b` in one file other in other half in other file)
If one value of `C2` itself is more than 30Mb then print the data associated with that `c2` into a file

I used pandas to do the same; my code

```
max_size = 30 * 1000000
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", low_memory=False)
unique_ac_id = pd.unique(df.C2)

counter = 1
df_arr = []
total_size = 0

for ac_id in unique_ac_id:
    df_cur = df[df.C2 == ac_id]
    size = df_cur.memory_usage(index=False, deep=True).sum()
    if size > max_size:
        print(f'{ac_id} size is more than max size allowded')

    if total_size > max_size:
        pd.concat(df_arr).to_csv(f'out/splitter_{counter}.csv', index=False)
        counter += 1
        df_arr.clear()
        total_size = 0

    df_arr.append(df_cur)
    total_size += size

if len(df_arr) > 0:
    pd.concat(df_arr).to_csv(f'out/splitter_{counter}.csv', index=False)
```

Is there a better way of doing the same?

Comment: The constraint is infeasible. What if half of your c2's are a? You wouldn't be able to condense it then.

Comment: It’s ok to pull all those to one file. In this case 30Mb need not be considered. In my data this case rarely happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily split that CSV into equal size chunks.

```
import pandas as pd
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('C:/your_path_here/main.csv', chunksize=100)):
    chunk.to_csv('chunk{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)...?

The syntax is pretty straightforward:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Using this approach, I'd just read 30MB at a time, and spool out the read contents to another csv.  Given you have the vector contents in `row`, you'll be able to ascertain the per-row size, and determine how many rows make ~30MB, so hopefully this will get you started.

Also, given the constraint about `c2`, you might end up opening up several csv's so that each csv will contain its respective `c2` grouping. Each row is a vector, so in the example you gave, that would appear to be the second element.